# UITableView adjust number of rows to row count in StoryBoard

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, tableview, swift5, xcode11

[image]

Hello, Im trying to automatically modify number of rows in my tableView to = the count in my Array. The data works fine and number of rows loads accordingly. However the table itself always shows 4 rows, it won't load more and won't show less even when less are loaded, just as you can see in the picture. Below is my script and settings.

```
extension FirstViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("click")
}
}

extension FirstViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      //  let a = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "RunwayRows")
       // return a
        return runways.count
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = runways[indexPath.row].ident1
    print(runways.count)

    return cell
}
}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Print `runways.count` before you return `numberOfRowsInSection`. See if you get what you expected.

Comment: The count works correctly, I think my problem comes from the layout. The number of available rows shows from the height of my table on storyboard, when I shrink the tableView I can see less and when I expand it I can see more. The rows itself fill correctly with information for the required number of rows.